# MagneticStripeReader.GetDefaultAsync(); returns null

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, windows-10

I have a usb connected MSR reader and i am trying to get it by using the sample codes proveded in [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Magnetic-stripe-reader-30aa2ca5). This works fine but the problem is when i add the same code to my app it doesn't work. GetDefaultAsync returns null.

```
private static MagneticStripeReader _reader = null;

public static async void StartRead()
{
    if (await CreateDefaultMagneticStripeReaderObject())
    {
        ....
    }
}

private static async Task<bool> CreateDefaultMagneticStripeReaderObject()
{
    if (_reader == null)
    {
        _reader = await MagneticStripeReader.GetDefaultAsync();
        if (_reader == null)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

My code is like above, very similer to sample but it doesnt work. Also i've added the device capability of pointOfService. So that is not the case.

Comment: As per [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn297987), `null` is returned when no device is found or access to the existing device is denied.

Comment: but the device is there. Sample app works just fine....

Comment: Somehow if i make the call in a async void method it works but it doesn't work in static method...

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong without seeing the entire code. I'm not sure why you've made it `static`.

Answer (score 1):

I was in the exact same situation and I spent the last 5 hours, finally I know what was going on. You are missing a capability in the Package.appxmanifest

'pointOfService' is the capability you want to include. This capability does not show in the UI and therefore I could not find any difference between my broken project and Microsoft's sample project. You can not add that capability using the UI. You have to manually add it by modifying the XML file.

The sample project by Microsoft have it too
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/MagneticStripeReader/cs/Package.appxmanifest#L53

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the card reader is in HID mode and not Keyboard emulation mode. That was one of my problems.

To do this is really wonky. MagTek has a ActiveX control on their website to assist us... because ActiveX is awful, you can only use it with InternetExplorer (it won't even work with Edge.)

go here in IE: https://www.magtek.com/changemode/

Enable active X when it pops up, and you can change from hid to keyboard and back.